# Does this statement turn into a nop?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, c-preprocessor, compiler-optimization

I am wondering if the code below, when the line `#define PRINT_STATEMENT` is commented out, will take many CPU cycles to execute on an ARM microcontroller:

```
#define PRINT_STATEMENT       1

#if PRINT_STATEMENT
   #define PRINT_DBG(...)     printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
   #define PRINT_DBG(...)
#endif

int main(){
   PRINT_DBG("Hello World\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I tested commenting out the `#define PRINT_STATEMENT` line on an online C compiler and can see that the print statement did not get executed. However, I am still wondering if the program were to be flashed onto an ARM microcontroller (with arm_gcc), will that line be turned into a `nop` operation?

Comment: After preprocessing nothing is left of that `PRING_DBG` call, just `;` which is an empty statement. Looking at it from the compiler perspective: would it make sense to turn every empty statement into a `nop`? Not really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is free to produce a nop or not. It's pretty much free to produce any program that does not print anything.

In modern compilers, preprocessing and compiling is done simultaneously. But in theory, the compiler gets the code after the preprocessor. And in that case, provided that you have set `PRINT_STATEMENT` to 0, the compiler will only see a main function with a sinle `return 0;` statement.

The standard does not dictate what should happen on this level. If you want to know what happened in your specific case with your compiler and your target, you will have to take a look at the assembly.

The most likely scenario is that it gets completely removed. Both because the compiler will not even see it, and because why produce a nop when you can produce nothing?

Answer (score 2):

> However, I am still wondering if the program were to be flashed onto an ARM microcontroller (with arm_gcc), will that line be turned into a nop operation?

Nothing simpler then test!

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#if PRINT_STATEMENT
    #define PRINT_DBG(...)     printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
    #define PRINT_DBG(...)
#endif
int main(){
   PRINT_DBG("Hello World\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Let's see that `printf` call:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -specs=nosys.specs -DPRINT_STATEMENT=1 main.c -o a.elf
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -D a.elf | sed '/<main>:/,/^$/!d'
0000820c <main>:
    820c:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr}
    8210:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
    8214:   e59f0014    ldr r0, [pc, #20]   ; 8230 <main+0x24>
    8218:   eb0000cc    bl  8550 <puts>
    821c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8220:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
    8224:   e24bd004    sub sp, fp, #4
    8228:   e8bd4800    pop {fp, lr}
    822c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    8230:   0000b5fc    strdeq  fp, [r0], -ip
```

Och! looks like `printf` was optimized to `puts`, *even* with optimizations disabled. Ok, anyway, let's see it without that nasty `printf`:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -specs=nosys.specs main.c -o b.elf
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -D b.elf | sed '/<main>:/,/^$/!d'
0000820c <main>:
    820c:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
    8210:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
    8214:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
    8218:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
    821c:   e28bd000    add sp, fp, #0
    8220:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
    8224:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

There is no `nop` instruction in there. Just instructions that are supposed to be there.

> will that line be turned into a nop operation?

No. That line will be "nonexistent".

Comment: And of course if you enable optimizations, you'll just get 2 instructions, none of this useless stack stuff or moving the return value to `r3` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it in compiler explorer: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/39Koxz

Here you can see that the main function compiled down to the `return 0;` part.

If you comment the `#define PRINT_STATEMENT` out the printf never makes it to the later compiler stages.

We can verify this using `gcc -E` with runs the pre-processor and prints the results:

```
$ gcc -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"
# 9 "test.c"
int main(){
   ;
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see the final code is just an empty main with a return 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Since there is no code to generate an operation, why does it not turn
> into an empty operation (as in consuming no CPU cycles)? If it is a
> nop, that would mean that it would take 1 CPU cycle?

Empty statements have no observable effects - thus no code generated.